# how to get session id on webhook

Tags: session, bots, actions-on-google, api-ai

I'm making assistant app for google home and Android mobile assistant

I'm using [action-on-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google) library on webhook which is recommended and handy

in my specific case I want to make [userEntity](https://api.ai/docs/reference/agent/userentities) from webhook which requires Session Id but **I am unable to get the sessionid on webhook**

according to [api.ai document](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#request) it sends Json to webhook like this:

```
{
    "lang": "en", 
    "status": {
        "errorType": "success", 
        "code": 200
    }, 
    "timestamp": "2017-02-09T16:06:01.908Z", 
    "sessionId": "1486656220806"              <<<<<<<<======here is session id
    "result": {
        "parameters": {
            "city": "Rome", 
            "name": "Ana"
        }, 
        "contexts": [], 
        "resolvedQuery": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
        "source": "agent", 
        "score": 1.0, 
        "speech": "", 
        "fulfillment": {
            "messages": [
                {
                    "speech": "Hi Ana! Nice to meet you!", 
                    "type": 0
                }
            ], 
            "speech": "Hi Ana! Nice to meet you!"
        }, 
        "actionIncomplete": false, 
        "action": "greetings", 
        "metadata": {
            "intentId": "9f41ef7c-82fa-42a7-9a30-49a93e2c14d0", 
            "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false", 
            "intentName": "greetings", 
            "webhookUsed": "true"
        }
    }, 
    "id": "ab30d214-f4bb-4cdd-ae36-31caac7a6693", 
    "originalRequest": {
        "source": "google", 
        "data": {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "raw_inputs": [
                        {
                            "query": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                            "input_type": 2
                        }
                    ], 
                    "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT", 
                    "arguments": [
                        {
                            "text_value": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                            "raw_text": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                            "name": "text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ], 
            "user": {
                "user_id": "PuQndWs1OMjUYwVJMYqwJv0/KT8satJHAUQGiGPDQ7A="
            }, 
            "conversation": {
                "conversation_id": "1486656220806", 
                "type": 2, 
                "conversation_token": "[]"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and ofcourse it is sending it correctly but on webhook we handover the request object to `action-on-google` and it returns an object with a bunch of methods like `ask`, `askWithCarousel`, `askWithList` and etc ([documented here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/ApiAiApp))

the problem is that there is not method to get conversation id documented
then how do i get that session id:

my source code for reference:

**/index.ts**

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { Request, Response } from "express"; //interfaces
const ActionsSdkApp = require('actions-on-google').ApiAiAssistant;

import db from '../db';

// API.AI Action names
import {
    inputWelcome
} from './actions'

const WELCOME_INTENT = 'input.welcome';

export const webhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (request: Request, response: Response) => {

    console.log("request.body: ", request.body);
    console.log("request.body.sessionId: ", request.body.sessionId);

    const app = new ActionsSdkApp({ request: request, response: response });

    let actionMap = new Map();
    actionMap.set(WELCOME_INTENT, inputWelcome);
    app.handleRequest(actionMap);
})//end of webhook http trigger
```

**/actions/index.ts**

```
import * as request from 'request';

export function inputWelcome(app: any) {

    //I WANT SESSION ID HERE

    console.log("app.conversation(): ", app.conversation());
    console.log("app.AppRequest: ", app.AppRequest);
    console.log("app.AppRequest.conversation: ", app.AppRequest.conversation);

    console.log("app.AppRequest(): ", app.AppRequest());
    console.log("app.AppRequest().conversation: ", app.AppRequest().conversation);


    console.log("app.getUser().accessToken;: ", app.getUser().accessToken)
    const accessToken = app.getUser().accessToken;

// MAKE USER ENTITY WITH THESE DATA:
//    {
//     "sessionId": "current conversation id here",
//     "entities": [
//         {
//             "name": "option1",
//             "entries": [
//                 {
//                     "value": "option1",
//                     "synonyms": [
//                         "first",
//                         "option one"
//                     ]
//                 }
//             ]
//         },
//         {
//             "name": "option2",
//             "entries": [
//                 {
//                     "value": "option2",
//                     "synonyms": [
//                         "second one",
//                         "second option"
//                     ]
//                 }
//             ]
//         },
//         {
//             "name": "option3",
//             "entries": [
//                 {
//                     "value": "option3",
//                     "synonyms": [
//                         "third one",
//                         "third option"
//                     ]
//                 }
//             ]
//         },
//         {
//             "name": "help",
//             "entries": [
//                 {
//                     "value": "help",
//                     "synonyms": [
//                         "help",
//                         "need help",
//                         "ditn't get",
//                         "need support"
//                     ]
//                 }
//             ]
//         }
//     ]
// }
//
// AND THEN ASK THE USER WITH SUGGESTION CHIPS    

    app.ask(app.buildRichResponse()
       .addSimpleResponse({
            speech: `Hi you can start with these things`,
            displayText: `Hi you can start with these things`
        })
        .addSuggestions(['option1', 'option2', 'option3', 'Help'])                        
    )
}
```

Comment: are you using actions-on-google node js client library ?

Comment: yes using actions-on-google https://www.npmjs.com/package/actions-on-google

Comment: You might be encountering the problem that API.AI sessionID comes from GAC conversation ID, and maybe you are testing via API.AI UI rather then GAC simulator.

Comment: I'm testing with GAC simulator

Comment: Currently there is no way to get the `sesssionId` when using the client library

Comment: @InzamamMalik did you check with `app.SessionId`?

Comment: yes @Webruster it is undefined

Comment: any alternative approach @matthewayne

Comment: currently i'm grabbing session id from request object and saving it in a variable for later use, but i think this is very bad practice

Answer (score 5):

support person said that:

> Hi,
>
> Thank you for your interest in Actions on Google. If you are using
>   nodejs for your webhook, you should be able to access the sessionId
>   with request.body.sessionId. You can store that value in a variable
>   and use it at later stages in the function.
>
> Kind Regards
>
> Jean-Charles, Actions on Google Support Team

[image]

Comment: yes that works but you are using TypeScript and not general Javascript Library

Comment: i have done it and it is working for me in typescript

Comment: but still looking for a clean solution